# Регулярные выражения и квантификаторы java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Мне нужно с помощью метода natches() узнать, есть ли в строке 1-2 цифры и 3-10 букв. При использовании следующего кода у меня получается false. В чем моя ошибка?

```
String dateAndMonth="44ааааа";
System.out.println(dateAndMonth.matches("[\\d]+{2}&&[A-Za-z]{3,10}"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[\\d]+{2}&&[A-Za-z]{3,10}` - это очень странное выражение. В Вашей строке ведь && нет?

По описанию должно быть где то так `\\d{2}[A-Za-z]{3,10}`

для условия **или** где то так `\d{1,2}|[A-Za-z]{3,10}`. Но java библиотека любит добавлять в начало и конец маркеры начала и конца, поэтому, лучше написать явно `.*(\d{1,2}|[A-Za-z]{3,10}).*`

Comment: мне казалось -еще нужно логическое И добавить. 
А как тогда сделать:узнать- есть ли в строке  1-2 цифры ИЛИ 3-10 букв?

Comment: стоп. **и** или **или**?

Comment: с "и" я понял- ничего добавлять не нужно,
а с "или" как?

Comment: Понял, значит (*. и .*)- это маркеры начала и конца, а как они будут выглядеть в методе, например: matches()?

Comment: нет, точка - это просто любой символ. Маркер начала строки - `^`, `$` - конца. `.*` - это читается как "любая последовательность символов".

Comment: Спасибо, как только смогу оценивать-  подарю плюс! :)

Answer (score 1):

`.*(\\d{1,2}.*[A-Za-z]{3,10})|([A-Za-z]{3,10}.*\\d{1,2}).*`

Comment: что означает точка после \\d{2}     ?
и почему вы использовали *, если нам нужно 1-2 цифры, а не "ноль и больше"?

Comment: `.` - любой символ. `*` - любое количество символов. `.*` используется, чтобы игнорировать промежуточные символы.  С `\\d{2}` осечка вышла)

Comment: то есть- если мы будем использовать одну точку в выражении: 
\\d{1,2}. - мы проигнорируем условие и допустим все символы?

Comment: `\\d{1,2}.` - это одна или две цифры, за которыми следует какой то один любой символ (в том числе цифра, буква, пробел и точка).

Comment: понял, благодарю!